# Using XslCompiledTransform in C# : xlst file compared to compiled dll

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transform

We're developing a program that generates DOCX files using XML and transforms. Currently one person is responsible for development of the XML and XSLT files and another for the C# program that puts it all together. I'm the one developing the C# side. Using the .xslt file the transform works fantastic. The issue I'm having is that the manager of this project doesn't want me to distribute the .xslt's. Instead I'm compiling the file into a dll assembly. No I'm getting errors such as:

*An error occurred while loading document ". See InnerExeption for a complete description of this error. This operation is not supported for a relative URI.*

I know it's probably something simple I've probably missed. Does anyone know of a good article that outlines the implementation difference between using the xlst file and a compiled dll.

Thanks.

Comment: Without code snippets it's hard to help you. Please post your code and the log error possibly.

Comment: Does the stylesheet try to use `document('')` to load and parse the stylesheet itself as an XML document?